# How can catch HTTP status code when we using RTK Query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I have one API, and I'm using `RTK Query`. 
In this API I want to catch `HTTP` StatusCode: 
I have `200` for one case and `204` for another case.

My services is:

```
export const api = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    initUser: builder.query({
      query: () => `${API_USER}`,
      
    }),
  }),
});
```

How can catch the value from the `HTTP` Status Code but not value from API object, because the status it `fulfilled` when `HTTP` Status Code = `200` and it `fulfilled` when HTTP Status Code = `204`. \

In both situations, API goes very well so the status is `fulfilled`

```
"status": "fulfilled",
"endpointName": "initUser",
"requestId": "Cq8LOOhf9dOeqkjylRq-d",
"originalArgs": {},
"startedTimeStamp": 1693835254873,
"data": null,
"fulfilledTimeStamp": 1693835255933,
"isUninitialized": false,
"isLoading": false,
"isSuccess": true,
"isError": false,
"currentData": null,
"isFetching": false
```

Comment: Please see my recent answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77716103/2099437

Answer (score 1):

Following the [documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#adding-meta-information-to-queries), use the `fetchBaseQuery` function to create your own `baseQuery` method. In your custom method, you will have access to the header status.

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

const customBaseQuery = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  const baseResult = await fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/"
  })(args, api, extraOptions);

  // Do something with response status code
  console.log(baseResult.meta?.response?.status);

  return baseResult;
};

export const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: customBaseQuery,
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getData: builder.query({
      query: (name: string) => `pokemon/${name}`
    })
  })
});

export const { useGetDataQuery } = api;
```