# RTK Query get Status code && error message from Error response

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am using Redux-Toolkit (RTK) Query with custom `baseQuery`

```js
const staggeredBaseQueryWithBailOut = retry(
  async (args: FetchArgs | string, api, extraOptions) => {
    try {
      const result = await fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: config.apiBaseURL,
        prepareHeaders: (headers, api) => {
          const {
            auth: { token }
          } = api.getState() as RootState
          if (isCustomQuery(args) && args.url === config.authURL) {
            headers.set("Authorization", `Basic ${config.basicToken}`)
          } else {
            if (token) headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`)
          }
        }
      })(args, api, extraOptions)
      if (result.error) throw result
      return result
    } catch (error) {
      return { error: error }
    }
  },
  {
    maxRetries: 2
  }
)
```

Whenever the API call fails, the API responds with `errorMessage`.

I want to get the `errorMessage` && the status code.

The error object returning from the `useQueryHook` is one generated by RTKQ with non-descriptive message like "FETCH_ERROR".

Is there a way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It figured out that the problem was with CORS Headers are not sent back in case of error response. just an API issue not an rtk query implementation error.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try it like this

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { logout } from "./slice/authSlice";

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
baseUrl: `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}`,
credentials: 'include',
prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
    const token = getState().auth.token
    if (token) {
        headers. Set("authorization", `Bearer ${token}`)
    }
    return headers
 }
})

const baseQueryWithReauth = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)

if (result?.error?.status === 403) {
    api.dispatch(logout())
    //console.log('sending refresh token')
    // send refresh token to get new access token 
   /* const refreshResult = await baseQuery('/refresh', api, extraOptions)
    console.log(refreshResult)
    if (refreshResult?.data) {
        const user = api.getState().auth.user
        // store the new token 
        api.dispatch(setCredentials({ ...refreshResult.data, user }))
        // retry the original query with new access token 
        result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)
    } else {
        api.dispatch(logout())
    }*/
}

  return result
}


export const api = createApi({
 baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
 reducePath: "adminApi",
 tagTypes: ["User", "Auth", "Customers"],
 endpoints: (build) => ({

    //auth
    login: build. Mutation({
        query: (body) => ({
            url: `users/login`,
            method: 'POST',
            body,
        }),
        invalidatesTags: ['User'],
    }),
    logout: build. Mutation({
        query: (body) => ({
            url: `users/logout`,
            method: 'PUT',
            body,
        }),
        invalidatesTags: ['User'],
    }),
    register: build. Mutation({
        query: (body) => ({
            url: `users/register`,
            method: 'POST',
            body,
        }),
        invalidatesTags: ['User'],
    }),
 })
})

export const {  useLogoutMutation, useLoginMutation, useRegisterMutation } = api;
```

Notice the way I picked the error `result?.error?.status === 403`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no status on result even nested.. I realized that this is an api error… I wasn’t getting CORS headers back in case of response error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if it's a `GET` method, you can do this

```
const {
 data: pokemonData,
 error: pokemonError, // <-- Get the error object
} = useGetPokemonQuery({
 name,
 token 
});
```

if it is a `POST` method, you can do this

```
const [addPokemon, { error : pokemonError }] = useAddPokemonMutation()
```

When you console.log the `error` object which is now in the variable `pokemonError` you will get

```
{
"data": {
 "data": {
  "message": "The requested resource was not found - 404"
},
 "status": "warning" 
},
 "status": 404 // <-- This is what you are looking for
}
```

PS: The JSON structure above largely depends on your API response

Answer (score 0):

```js
const staggeredBaseQueryWithBailOut = retry(
  async (args: FetchArgs | string, api, extraOptions) => {
    try {
      const result = await fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: config.apiBaseURL,
        prepareHeaders: (headers, api) => {
          const {
            auth: { token }
          } = api.getState() as RootState
          if (isCustomQuery(args) && args.url === config.authURL) {
            headers.set("Authorization", `Basic ${config.basicToken}`)
          } else {
            if (token) headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`)
          }
        }
      })(args, api, extraOptions)
      if (result.error) throw result
      return result
    } catch (error) {
      return { error: error }
    }
  },
  {
    maxRetries: 2
  }
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).